# SLAM implementation with Kinect and the current shortcomings

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,i am an undergraduate and i want to do my thesis on SLAM implementation with Kinect(if any way possible). But the thing is,i am getting lost searching the net for the summary of the recent SLAM implementations using kinect and the current shortcomings of the algorithms for kinect.So,the things i need to know are-

1.Recent SLAM implementations using kinect
2.Their current shortcomings
3.Current improvement research on SLAM using kinect
4.And,most importantly.... " A GOOD DISCUSSION ON "SLAM WITH KINECT" "

u see that i am kinda lost already.So, can anyone please help me out ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59500/slam-implementation-with-kinect-and-the-current-shortcomings/) by [Hasnat.iut09](https://answers.ros.org/users/4561/hasnat.iut09/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-03-28

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2013-03-28**:
I dont think this is a 'suitable' topic for a final year project and even worse if there is no graduate student guiding u..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently posted about a number of open source implementations of Kinect-Based SLAM on [my blog](http://www.showusyoursensors.com/2013/02/3d-mapping-is-here.html). That said, I would agree with others that this is a pretty hard problem. You might consider breaking off something less ambitious that builds on other people's work and still lets you explore a number of interesting things, rather than trying to create an entire implementation.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0